# Difference equations in R

Tags: r, recursion, model

Below is a parasite growth model:

[image: Ni(a,t) represents the expected number of parasites of age a at time t]

Ni(a, t) represents the expected number parasites of age a at time t, and ki(a, t) represents the killing effect, while PMF the multiplication factor. This is a discrete model as a equals 1, 2, 3.....48. Can anybody tell me how to implement this equation in R using difference equations? Many thanks for your support.

Comment: Have you tried searching for an answer online? First hit on google: http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010-2/RJournal_2010-2_Soetaert~et~al.pdf

Comment: I tried but did not find anything that could be of help. The major obstacle for me is the conditional growth, and there's also the discrete data type instead of continuous.

Comment: Is time being advanced in integer steps? Have you considered using memoization, where you build a lookup table of N(a,t) values so you can short-circuit repeated re-evaluation in the recursion?

Answer (score 2):

This is the best I could do with the information you provided. Point me to the rest of it and I might be able to get it to actually work, as stands I think it'll recur infinitely.

```
 Ki <- function(a, t){ ## You need to actually define this properly
      return(1)
    }

    Ni <- function(a, t, PMF){
      if ((a %% 1 != 0)) stop("Only Takes Integer values of a")
      if ((t %% 1 != 0)) stop("Only Takes Integer values of t")

      if (a == 1){
        x = Ni(48, t-1, PMF)
        y = exp(-Ki(48,t-1))
        result = PMF * x * y
        return(result)
      }

      if (a > 1){
        x = Ni(a-1, t-1, PMF)
        y = exp(-Ki(a-1,t-1))
        result = x * y
        return(result)
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a set of initial conditions. Once you've got some initial 48 values for N(a=1..48,t=1) you compute N(a=1,t=2) from the second equation, and then compute N(a=2..48,t=2) from the first equation. Repeat for t=3 and so on.

What you have is a recurrence relation, not a differential equation. You step through a recurrence relation as I've just explained.

It might be possible to convert this to a system of differential equations by looking at N(t)-N(t-1)/dt and solving but that's a maths job not a programming job.

Comment: He's got a difference equation,(a type of recurrence relation) as he says in the body of the question, not a differential equation.